# I cannot see an ad added by a script when I navigate from and back to a page in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, single-page-application

I have a small react app where I am supposed to add an ad. I have a script that loads the ads to the ins placeholders.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function AdsComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://example.example.net/js/code.min.js';
        script.async = true;
        script.setAttribute('data-cfasync', 'false');
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='mt-[2rem] mr-[2rem]'>
            <ins className='aso-zone' data-zone='96230'></ins>
            <ins className='aso-zone' data-zone='96231'></ins>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AdsComponent;
```

**The problem :** When I navigate to  another page and back to the one with the ad. The ad does not show.
**On initial page load or refresh**

[on initial page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZA0p.png)

**On navigating to another page and back:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSp5Z.png).

Is there a way to ensure that on navigating the ad is reloaded?

Comment: Please, show how do you use that component =) there is nothing inside AdsComponent that helps to understand what's going on

Comment: and also it's nice to see what's inside that script, as it might react on already modified DOM container for ads

Comment: I found the problem to  be with the ad service provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to be with the ad service provider. I managed
to solve the problem by caching the ad on inial load to session storage
and using the cached version on subsequent rerenders